# Passive vga to dvi-d adapter?

Tags: vga, dvi

Recently I've found a *vga to dvi-d* article on ebay. Yes, it is vga to dvi-*d*. Its price (around $10), its outlook, and also the absence of an external power plug show clearly that it isn't an active adapter.

[image: dvi side - no analog pins][image: vga side - analog by standard]

The layout shows clearly that it converts the vga signal to a dvi-*d* signal, i.e. the dvi part hasn't the analog pins.

(Unfortunately, I can't put its link here, because it could be seen as spam.)

The device produced a large sales (more than a thousand), so it is surely not some type of crap. How is it possible?

*Extension #1: It seems I can put its link here, at least temporarily, see the comments.*

Comment: That's strange. And I don't see how it could work.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thank you. My first idea was that it is a cheat. My second idea that despite its outlook and its low price, it may contain some type of an active electronics, although in would need probably an external power supply, too.

Comment: The design's identical to a passive connector. And sticking a link might be useful - maybe as a comment. I'd be less worried about it being seen as spam than it going away.

Comment: These things are usually intended to be used in conjunction with a digital to analog converter box (though they often gloss over that fact when selling them).  Do a search on amazon and you'll find similar products that do actually state this.

Comment: Here is the link of the device: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DVI-female-to-VGA-male-adapter-DVI-D-dual-link-24-1-/180585530288?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a0bbc83b0

Comment: @Paul I contacted the seller. You had right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the seller about this, and the answer I've got validated @Paul's hyphothese, which is unfortunately deleted in the comments. In essence, the solution is the following:

This adapter converts only the plug layouts, but not the signals. It can be used only with the conjunction of an active adapter box.

Or, it can make also possible to transmit DVI-D or VGA signals on a *physical*, *passive* VGA/DVI-D tunnel, for example on some type of multiplexer.

Although the seller doesn't mention it explicitly, it also means, that at least on one of the plugs we get a highly extraordinary signal (digital signal on analog pins or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, with the onset of newer PCB-printing technology, companies have made tiny microchips, small enough to fit in the plug of the sockets. It could be possible that a PCB inside these plugs is doing the conversion.

Comment: Thank you. But in this case, at least on one of the outputs should we have a highly non-standard signal (analog signal on digital pins or vice versa). Is it possible, even in the case if it requires an external box to the active electronics?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understand your question. Could you please rephrase it for me?